# Is “HANA database master” user the SYSTEM user?

Tags: hana

I installed HANA Express in a VMware Workstation environment, and also Eclipse 4.6 with the HANA administrator plugin. Both VMWare and Eclipse run on Windows 10. I can start HANA with no issues, however when I try to connect from the Eclipse plugin the connection fails.

The tutorial to configure the HANA administrator plugin in Eclipse instructs to enter SYSTEM as user and then a password. The problem is that in the HANA Express tutorial the only user that seems to be set up is the "database master" (see text below). Therefore, I don't have the SYSTEM password and I don't know the "database master" user (even though I know the password). How to make this work?

```
Step 3: Startup: Configuration Script
A configuration script will run if this is the first login. When prompted 
for HANA database master password, enter a strong password.

Tip: Make a note of this password, since you’ll need it later. You can enter 
the same password you used earlier, or a new password. If you are entering a 
new password, see the password rules earlier in this tutorial.

XSA_ADMIN

XSA_DEV

XSA_SHINE

TEL_ADMIN

When prompted to Confirm “HANA database master password”, enter the strong
password again.
```

This is the error I get in Eclipse log:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SYSTEM password is the same as the master database password for HXE. If that does not work, try *HXEHana1*

Also, I see you are trying to connect to instance number 00. If the HXE VM is 2.0 sps00 or higher, the default instance number is 90.

You can rule out connectivity problems by running the following from the Virtual Machine's console:

```
hdbsql -n localhost -i 90 -d SYSTEMDB -u SYSTEM
```

This will connect to your instance and prompt for the password for user SYSTEM so you can confirm which one is right before configuring HANA Studio.

Comment: Thanks Lucia, instance 90 did the trick, SAP needs to update this tutorial: https://www.sap.com/developer/how-tos/2016/09/hxe-howto-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I used user : XSA_ADMIN and the HANA password chosen as part of the tutorial.

Its now connected.

Regards